# can't understand the syntax of [lsort [::array names my_array *,dut_inst]]

Tags: tcl

I can't understand this:

```
[lsort [::array names my_array *,dut_inst]]
```

What meaning of * ?
What meaning of dut_inst ?

Where can I read about it ?

Let's assume:

```
my_array(0)=0
my_array(1)=1
my_array(2)=2
```

What will I get ?

Answer (score 2):

That optional argument to [`array names`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/array.htm#M9) is an optional *glob pattern* that is used to filter the results to return down to a subset. The rules for how it works are described in the [documentation for `string match`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35), but in the case of `*,dut_inst` we have two parts:

1. `*` matches *any* number of characters.
2. `,dut_inst` is literal (as none of the characters in it are special in the `string match` rules).

The *effect* is to return a list of all element names whose names *end* with `,dut_inst`. With your sample data, you get an empty list. With this sample data:

```
my_array(foo,bar)=1
my_array(boo,dut_inst)=2
my_array(dut_inst,grill)=3
my_array(abc,dut_inst,def)=4
my_array(pqr,dut_inst)=5
```

You'd get this output (assuming the `lsort` is there; Tcl *does not* guarantee the order of array iteration): `boo,dut_inst pqr,dut_inst`

Comment: The mode is called glob matching, and is approximately what shells use to match filenames. Tcl's own `glob` command uses an extended version of it…